# check boundries in random iterator implementaion postfix and prefix

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement Vector class Iterator (similar to stl classes) and I'm not sure if I need to check boundries before I increases/ decreases the iterator.
If I dont need to check so what happens if there is an exception, and if I do need to check whan happens if there is an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard doesn't require `std::vector::iterator::operator++` check. Incrementing it past `end`, or decrementing past `begin` is undefined behaviour.

Undefined behaviour **doesn't** mean "throws an exception". Because it is undefined, an implementation that throws is valid, and so is an implementation that reads adjacent memory.

If you want to define your `Vector` class to throw when out-of-range, you can. This will require that your iterator have access to the limits of the range, which means more member variables. Typically `std::vector<T>::iterator` holds (or *is*) one `T*`.

Comment: so (vector.end() ++)++ should be possible?

Comment: @Danielle what do you mean *possible*? It's valid syntax, but undefined behaviour for `std:vector`